# How can I write to my java logback log the properties the tomcat server is running with on startup?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'd like to see some of the property settings in my log of what the java server is initialized with. Not on each request just at startup. How can I set that up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it might be to create a `ServletContextListener` that logs the properties in the `contextInitialized` method.  For example:

```
public class LoggingServletContextListener
           implements ServletContextListener {

  private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LoggingServletContextListener.class);

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

  }

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    logger.info(System.getProperties());      
  }
}
```

You would need to include the listener in your `web.xml` file.  You can read more about `ServletContextListener` here:

- https://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/